# Why do which and Sys.which return different paths?

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I tried to run a Python script from R with:

```
system('python script.py arg1 arg2')
```

And got an error:

> ImportError: No module named pandas

This was a bit of a surprise since the script was working from the terminal as expected. Having encountered this type of issue before (with `knitr`, whence the [`engine.path`](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_knitr_engines.html) chunk option), I know to check:

```
Sys.which('python')
#            python 
# "/usr/bin/python"
```

And compare it to the command line:

```
$ which python
# /Users/michael.chirico/anaconda2/bin/python
```

(i.e., the error arises because I have `pandas` installed for the anaconda distribution, though TBH I don't know why I have a different distribution)

Hence I can fix my issue by running:

```
system('/Users/michael.chirico/anaconda2/bin/python script.py arg1 arg2')
```

My question is two-fold:

- How does R's `system`/`Sys.which` find a different `python` than my terminal?
- How can I fix this besides writing out the full binary path each time?

I read `?Sys.which` for some hints, but to no avail. In particular, `?Sys.which` suggests `Sys.which` *is using `which`*:

> This is an interface to the system command `which`

This is clearly (?) untrue; to be sure, I checked `Sys.which('which')` and `which which` to confirm both are pointing to `/usr/bin/which` (goaded on by this tidbit):

> On a Unix-alike the full path to which (usually `/usr/bin/which`) is found when R is installed.

To the latter, on a whim I tried `Sys.setenv(python = '/Users/michael.chirico/anaconda2/bin/python')` to no avail.

Comment: Looking forward to answers, I had a bash script last week that worked from the terminal but not from the system command within R, but didn't take the time to debug or write it up as a question. (It was a one-off, so I lazily just ran it from terminal.)

Comment: Assuming all the whiches are obeying the `$PATH`, the `$PATH` must be different - what's `system("echo $PATH")` in R and `echo $PATH` in the shell? Is that consistent with which `python` `which` finds? Is `system("which python")` to same as `Sys.which("python")`?

Comment: @Spacedman good suggestions, and you're on to something, in fact my `anaconda2/bin` directory is on my _terminal's_ `$PATH`, but not on the path known to `system` in R. Given that, I guess it's no surprise `system('which python')` is the same as `Sys.which('python')` (that much was basically clear from the fact that the `python` found by `system` didn't have `pandas` attached)

Comment: So the question is: is there a non-hackish way to set the `PATH` in sync? I could obviously copy-paste what I found in the terminal to `Sys.setenv(PATH=...)`

Comment: `??PATH` doesn't seem to turn up any relevant (new) help pages FWIW

Comment: So you run R *from a terminal that has `anaconda2/bin` in the PATH* but that doesn't appear in `system("echo $PATH")`?

Comment: @Spacedman no, but another great question. Better, closer, warmer. This is from Rstudio. As expected, if I run R in the terminal, this issue does not arise. I've added the `rstudio` tag.

Comment: Curiously, if I go to Rstudio's `Terminal` tab, `which python` returns the "correct" (`anaconda2`) path...

Comment: So how do you launch RStudio? From a menu? In which case it gets the PATH from the process that started the desktop. Start RStudio from the terminal command line? That should get the terminal's PATH....

Comment: The RStudio terminal will run your startup scripts for a login shell, so that's likely why it gets the same path as your outside shell.

Comment: You should never install Anaconda. Pure crap that messes everything, loads a lot of additional crap that you don't need and plays with your environment vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some of the comments hint, this is a problem that arises because the `PATH` environment variable is different for programs launched by Finder (or the Dock) than it is in the Terminal. There are ways to set the `PATH` for Dock-launched applications, but they aren't pretty. Here's a place to start looking if you want to go that route:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications

The other thing you can do, which is probably more straightforward, is tell R to set the `PATH` variable when it starts up, using `Sys.setenv` to add the path to your desired Python instance. You can do that for just one project, for your whole user account, or for the whole system, by placing the command in a `.Rprofile` file in the corresponding location. More information on how to do this here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html

Comment: I wish there was a way to launch a standard terminal from within the finder-launched R instance. I'd be happy to just add a `Sys.setenv(PATH = foo())` if there was a straightforward way to design said `foo`

Comment: The main answer in the linked question didn't work for me, but this one did: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198282/257940