# Calling Rust cargo from R results in "cargo not found" error on macOS

Tags: r, rust

Running R from RStudio on macOS 11.2.1

When calling cargo from R, as when using the [rextendr](https://github.com/extendr/rextendr) package or trying to install [helloextendr](https://github.com/extendr/helloextendr), I receive the errors `sh: cargo: command not found` and `make: cargo: command not found`, respectively. However, from the terminal, calling `cargo` works as expected.

One can see the difference from below.

In R cargo is not found:

```
> Sys.which("cargo")
# cargo
# ""
```

From a terminal cargo is found

```
% which cargo
$HOME/.cargo/bin/cargo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is related to this question: [Why do which and Sys.which return different paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084679/why-do-which-and-sys-which-return-different-paths) Simply put, macOS has a different $PATH variable, depending on whether you use a terminal directly or use an application launched from the dock (as R and RStudio are).

One solution is to use a .Rprofile file. Add the following lines to the .Rprofile in your home directory or project's home directory. (For more on .Rprofile files, see [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf).)

```
# R can't find Rust's cargo binary
# issue is because $PATH is different for shell vs. dock launched applications in MacOS
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084679/why-do-which-and-sys-which-return-different-paths
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0("/Users/username/.cargo/bin:", Sys.getenv("PATH")))
```

Make sure "username" is your username. For example, my path is "/Users/tommy/.cargo/bin:"

This appends the [default location of Rust installation](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Rust%20development%20environment,cargo%2Fbin&text=directory%2C%20and%20this%20is%20where,in%20their%20PATH%20environment%20variable.) to the $PATH variable that R receives on startup.